# Ads receiving clicks, but not actual traffic (phantom clicks from multiple ad platforms)

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, gdpr, eu-cookie-law

I am not receiving ad traffic from Facebook ads, Google Search ads, or Reddit ads to my website any more, despite receiving clicks on my ads across all these platforms. This is according to multiple analytics tools I am using to monitor my site:

1. **Google Analytics** is reporting only 4 clicks from my target area (55mi radius of Sacramento, CA), rather than the 50 reported by my Search ad. And those 4 clicks are most likely just me checking out the site.
2. **HotJar** is recording traffic from across the globe just fine (primarily from my Reddit posts), but none from the ads (or even from the US), other than a test link I clicked in the Google Ads setting page for this Search ad to verify that it works. HotJar registered the click just fine.
3. My **Firestore** database is not reporting any other search activity in the main search bar of my site.

I used to be able to see the traffic just fine from Facebook Ads with HotJar (my primary analysis tool) and view recordings of my user's activity, although only ~10% of the clicks reported by Facebook Ads would appear in HotJar. Now with my latest Google Search ad, I am not seeing *any* ad traffic, despite Google Ads reporting 50 clicks after $108 spent ($2.12 CPC).

Are these ad platforms preventing traffic from actually clicking through to my site?

PS: Would these ad platforms block traffic to websites that don't have a cookie-accept policy or if the site is not GDPR compliant?

[image]